# Selenium Comparison

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am working on a Selenium test using WebDriver in Java.  I have a compare that isn't comparing.  The code looks like this:

```
if("20".equals(UserMaintenancePage.UserCount.getText()))
```

The value of the UserCount element is definitely 20 but it always fails the compare.

I tried slapping a `.toString()` on the end with the same result.

This one has me scratching my head.

Thanks

Comment: What is the result of `System.out.println(UserMaintenancePage.UserCount.getText())`?

Comment: Please post the content of the entire `if` block .

Comment: a little more code would help.  please include the PageObjects for `UserMaintenancePage.UserCount`, as well as an HTML snippet of the element you are attempting to get the text of

Comment: Maybe some additional trailing or leading whitespaces are present. Try a `.trim()` call to remove them

Comment: if("20".equals(UserMaintenancePage.UserCount.getText()))
   test.log(LogStatus.PASS, "UserMaintenancePage - Record Count Passed"));
else
   test.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "UserMaintenancePage - Record Count Failed ");

Comment: @stevepurcell, please edit your question with the code. don't comment

Comment: @stevepurcell  store that 20 in String then use equalsof

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
String val = UserMaintenancePage.UserCount.getText();
int intVal = Integer.parseInt(val);
if(intVal == 20) {
// to do your message
}
```

Comment: hashcode is not same on his case, So I made this tricks @sircapsalot

Comment: the problem is, what if this `parseInt` fails?  the code you have here won't compile.  also, since `getText` returns a string, you are just adding more to the compiler than necessary when a string comparison is just as good

Comment: I agree with you @sircapsalot

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = Integer.toString("20");
```

if(str.equal(UserMaintenancePage.UserCount.getText()))
{}

Answer (score 0):

I think the code might be failing due to "`UserMaintenancePage.UserCount.getText()`" is returning "20 " or " 20" instead of "20". So you can use .trim() function to clear blank spaces. I hope below mentioned code works for you:

```
if("20".equals(UserMaintenancePage.UserCount.getText().trim()))
{
// write your code..
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

There were occasional extra characters getting into the webelement.  Placing a .trim() on it everytime solved the problem.

Thanks for bearing with me on here.